# Tsql query to change date and time

Tags: t-sql, date, dynamic

How can I have the below query to change the date and time. I have to execute the query by changing the time and date for entire month. Thank you for your help.

```
Select Column1
From table 
Where (date1 <‘2011-11-11 11:00’ and date2 >’2011-11-11 11:00’)
And column 2 = ‘something’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table 
set date1 = .....  
Where (date1 < '2011-11-11 11:00' and date2 > '2011-11-11 11:00')
  And column 2 = 'something'
```